# Developing a Betting Slip in Javascript

Tags: javascript, gambling

I'm Project Managing a gambling site and they are looking for a bet slip to handle all of their Sports Book betting.

There are two good JS staff working in my team that will be tasked with this but I'd like to point them in the direction of best practices and things to look for.

The slip is going to be quite complicated, so having a simple framework on which to build may spark some ideas they wouldn't have otherwise had.

I realise this is a very lame question, but it'd help out the team a lot if people can point us in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

1. Definitely use a JavaScript framework for this. There's a good discussion on the popular frameworks here - [what javascript library would you choose for a new project and why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913/what-javascript-library-would-you-choose-for-a-new-project-and-why). Use the plugin architecture of whichever framework you choose to componentize common functionality.
2. Don't rely solely on the client-side for input integrity and validation - validate ***everything*** server-side too